# Position y tick lines at both sides of the border

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, angular, chart.js

I try to make a chart using chart.js. It should look like following (tick line at both side of border): [image: expected chart].

All I achieved so far:

[image: current chart]

How can I draw tick line at both sides of a border? Or there is other solution for this?

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script>

    var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["17"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "My First dataset",
                data: [0],
                fill: false
            },
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                data: [100],
                fill: false
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            clip: false,
            scales: {
                x: {
                    grid: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    border: { display: false },
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: "green",
                        fontSize: 18,
                        stepSize: 1,
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    grid: {
                        display: true,
                        drawTicks: true,  //show ticks
                        borderColor: "transparent", //horizontal line color above ticks (x-axis)
                        color: "transparent",   //grid lines color
                        tickColor: "#868e96"  //ticks color (little line above points)
                    },
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    max: 100,
                    ticks: {
                        // forces step size to be 20 units
                        stepSize: 20,
                        crossAlign: 'far',
                        // align: 'center',
                        // mirror: true
                    }
                },
            },
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, config);

</script>
```

I can achieve tick line at one way, but can't achieve it at both ways simultaneously.

Comment: A natural solution would be to use the horizontal grid lines, not tick marks, and control the horizontal extension of the chart canvas, as for instance in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5kpruqdw/).